# How to get result from each function inside map function in functional programming/ReactJS?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to functional programming and having issues with map function. I am trying to call one function on each map call and after every result of that function, I want to get results and give the value of that result to the list I am mapping/looping

Code

```
 customerList = customerList .map(
        (customer) =>
          (result = getCustomerAddress(customer.id)),
          customer.city = result.city,
          customer.state = result.state
      );
```

This is not working. It says customer is not defined. I know it is a syntax issue. I am not familiar with functional style of programming. I am trying to just call getCustomerAddress on each Id and then give the values of address to each customer.

Comment: Define your blocks properly https://jsfiddle.net/c7m60s5b/2/

Comment: "*It says customer is not defined. I know it is a syntax issue.*" - what exactly does it say? It looks more like `customer` has the value `undefined`, on which you cannot access the `.id` property.

Answer (score 0):

There is no declaration of the `result` variable. You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract `city` and `state` from `getCustomerAddress` function and then return a new object using the existing `customer` props along with `city` and `state`:

```
customerList = customerList.map(customer => {
  const { city, state } = getCustomerAddress(customer.id);
  return { ...customer, city, state };
});
```

If you still get a `customer` undefined error, then make sure the `customerList` array is properly filled with customer data.